# window.parent not working in jsni

Tags: gwt, iframe, gxt, jsni

I am using GXT's sencha

We have a web application named "dashboard"
 **url = localhost:8080/dashboard/**

We have another webapplication named issuetracker

**url = localhost:2990/issuetracker/**

Now i have a velocity template in the issuetracker web application in which i have given the following code

```
<iframe src="localhost:8080/dashboard" width="500" height="600">
</iframe>
```

When i click a button in the dashboard web application the url of the issuetracker application should change like "localhost:8080/issuetracker/issues?mqlVersion=25". 
This 25 value comes from the dashboard web application.

When i tried writing jsni code none of the following values showed up
the top most window's url which is "localhost:2990/issuetracker/"

- $wnd.top.location
- $wnd.top.location.href
- $wnd.parent.location.href
- $wnd.parent.location
- window.top.location
- window.top.location.href
- window.parent.location.href
- window.parent.location

Where am i going wrong?
Any suggestions.

Comment: Please remember that there are now 1.a browser with iframe 2.This iframe's src is pointing to a GWT application. 3. The GWT application has a iframe inside which the actual web application is seen. So it is like two iframes. iframe inside iframe

Comment: It depends on your html/jsp file.

Comment: it is like one iframe written by me to include the GWT application. The other iframe generated by the GWT web application.

Comment: If this is the case then try with `$wnd.parent.parent.location.href`

Answer (score 1):

> Use `$wnd` in JSNI instead of `window`.

Try (clean browser cache)

JSNI

```
Window.Location.replace(url);

public static final native String getParentWindow() /*-{
    return $wnd.parent.location.href;
}-*/;
```

JSP/HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeURL() {
    try {
        window.parent.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/issuetracker/issues?mqlVersion=25';
    } catch (e) {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/issuetracker/issues?mqlVersion=25';
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

Sample code

JSP/HTML

```
<div>
    <div id='myDiv'>hello</div>
    <iframe src="localhost:8080/dashboard" width="500" height="600">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

dashboard Entry Point class:

```
public static final native Element getParentElementById(String id) /*-{
    return $wnd.parent.document.getElementById(id);
}-*/;

....

public void onModuleLoad() {
     getParentElementById("myDiv").setInnerHTML("hi");
}
```

Output:

Inner HTML `hello` of `myDiv` is replaced with `hi`.

Comment: should i use any one of these 
Window.Location.replace(url)                                             OR
public static final native String getParentWindow() /*-{
    return $wnd.parent.location.href;
}-*/;

Comment: How you will get `url` passed in ` Window.Location.replace()`?

Comment: i tried Window.Location.replace() and the iframe url is modified. i have to try the other one now

Comment: What you passed in  Window.Location.replace()?

Comment: The modified url "/issues?mqlVersion=25"